# Limited Swipe Area Android

Tags: android

I need to limit the swipe area inside a ViewPager. For example, if the user make the gesture to swipe on top half space of the screen it swipe to the next fragment, but if the user make the gesture on the bottom half of the screen it do nothing.

There is a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be a what you need:

```
public class MyPager extends ViewPager {
    public MyPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if(inNeutralArea(ev.getX(),ev.getY())){
            //--events re-directed to this ViewPager's onTouch() and to its child views from there--
            return false; 
        }else {
            //--events intercepted by this ViewPager's default implementation, where it looks for swipe gestures--
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        }
    }

    private boolean inNeutralArea(float x, float y) {
        //--check if x,y inside non reactive area, return true/false accordingly--
        return false;
    }

}
```

Use this `MyPager` class in layout xml in place of `ViewPager`.

Comment: hey user117, do you know how to set some property value from xml file?

Comment: could u plz let us know how to add this in layout xml?  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to do to the same in overriding the **onTouchEvent**, otherwise the ViewPager will still scroll on Android 4.1 and later. Caught me ofguard and took me a while to figure it out.